# file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use file_get_contents() to grab only Name from fake name generator site(https://fakena.me/fake-name/), however I'm getting the following warning:

```
file_get_contents() stream does not support seeking
```

I dont need entire content of the page. I need only Name section in this site: https://fakena.me/fake-name/.

My code:

```
$name= file_get_contents('https://fakena.me/fake-name/', NULL, NULL, 849, 32);
```

Its working well in localhost, showing error only in live website.

Answer (score 4):

You can read about it in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files. Attempting to
>   seek on non-local files may work with small offsets, but this is
>   unpredictable because it works on the buffered stream.

What you can do is use `substr` after what you retrive the contents of the page:

```
$part = substr($name, 849, 32);
```

Comment: Awesome. Its working..thanks a million.& file_get_contents is very slow.. How to speed up that? @Federkun

Comment: if `$name` is a very long string, you can work with a php stream, Guzzle: https://github.com/guzzle/streams/blob/master/src/LimitStream.php

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the offset issue in the latest versions

Here we need to change the $offset value from -1 t0 1

```
  public static function file_get_html( $url, $use_include_path = false, $context = null, $offset = 1, $maxLen = -1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed = true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN = true, $defaultBRText = DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText = DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT )
        {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you scraping website? Lots of free APIs are available for fake name generator.

```
TRY:  https://uinames.com/api/
```

You will get output in JSON format. Decode it using json_decode() and use for your purpose and also it's fast as compared to scraping.

**Optional Parameters**

The number of names to return, between 1 and 500:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?amount=25
```

Limit results to the male or female gender:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?gender=female
```

Region-specific results:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?region=germany
```

Require a minimum number of characters in a name:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?minlen=25
```

Require a maximum number of characters in a name:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?maxlen=75
```

For JSONP, specify a callback function to wrap results in:

```
https://uinames.com/api/?callback=example
```