# file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking ／ When was PHP behavior about this changed?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

**When was PHP behavior about this changed?**

From which PHP version is it?

---

> Warning: file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking in
> /simple_html_dom.php
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to seek to position -1 in the stream in
> /simple_html_dom.php

---

```
include('parser/simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow";
$html = file_get_html($url);
if ($html !== false) {
  foreach($html->find('div#mw-content-text') as $item){
    $item->plaintext;
  }
}
```

Comment: this ocurrs in PHP 7.1, but in 7.0 an d 5.6 work fine.

Comment: This compatibility issue has been fixed in 1.7 onwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816714/file-get-contents-stream-does-not-support-seeking-php)

You are working with a remote file. Seeking is only supported for local files.

You probably need to copy the file to your local file system before using `file_get_html`. It should work fine on localhost.

Comment: Does PHP behaviors have not been changed?
Is this specification unchanged from the past?

Comment: According to the changelog http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php there has been no change regarding seeking on remote files. That's why I assume you previously only worked with local files for which seeking is fine (or you where lucky, as sometimes seeking might work on small ranges for remote files, too, according to the doc).

Comment: thanks. >sometimes seeking might work on small ranges for remote files, too, according to the doc

Answer (score 106):

I had the same issue on my page when I moved it from one system to another, I was able to change the `simple_html_dom.php` file by removing the offset reference (didn't cause any further problems for me).

On line 75 of `simple_html_dom.php`:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
```

I removed the reference to `$offset`:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context);
```

No my page works fine. Not taking liability for anything else it breaks! :)

Answer (score 23):

Change

```
function file_get_html(..., $offset = -1,...)
```

to

```
function file_get_html(..., $offset = 0,...)
```

in simple_html_dom.php

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to edit the vendor files. Just change your requests from:

```
$html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/");
```

to:

```
$html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html( "https://www.google.com/", false, null, 0 );
```

The problem is that the default offset used by Simple HTML DOM is "-1" when you want it to be "0". Luckily it accepts it as a parameter, which means you can change it easily without needing to change the Simple HTML DOM source.

**Note:** This compatibility issue was fixed in v1.7+

Comment: Correct answer if using a Composer version

Answer (score 2):

Others have shared the solution, but no one has shared why. I don't know specifically why this is different between PHP 7.0 & 7.1, but the [PHP.net docs for this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) say:

> Seeking (offset) is not supported with remote files. Attempting to
>   seek on non-local files may work with small offsets, but this is
>   unpredictable because it works on the buffered stream.

I can confirm that removing the offset parameter in `file_get_contents` on line 75 works for me and/or setting the offset to 0 in the `file_get_html` function on line 70 works too.

I guess that the offset parameter was never meant to be used with non local files since:

> The offset where the reading starts on the original stream. Negative
>   offsets count from the end of the stream.

Hope this helps clear up any confusion. With external sources, it makes sense to start streaming from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Set $offset = 0

That is working!

Answer (score 0):

first, try to change simple_html_dom.php like

- remove the offset parameter from file_get_contents(...) on line 75
- OR set the offset to 0 in file_get_html func on line 70

**if still not works** ??? like mine

then it means you have the latest version of PHP and you need to download the latest version of simple_html_dom.php from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

after that, it works for me on each machine and system