# Can't Scrape Price in HTML_dom and curl

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

Hey guys i got this weird problem i am trying to scrape product price from Aliexpress using _SIMPLE_HTML_DOM and it is not working because the source code can be find Inspect element but i can't find the source in when i go into CTRL+U

For Example

[image]

Now This is the source code when i press ctrl + u

[image]

This is the Code i am using to scrape

```
$curl->get('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32844492002.html');
$response = $curl->getRawResponse();
$html4 = new simple_html_dom();
$html4->load($response);
$price2 = $html4->find("div[class='product-price'] div[class='product-price-current'] span[class='product-price-value']",0)->plaintext;
echo $price2;
```

I am Getting This Error :

> Notice: Trying to get property 'plaintext' of non-object

Comment: Hi perhaps try to print out the raw `$response` and see if it contains what you're looking for? If it's not there, maybe the site is building that content dynamically in some way. If it is there, try to simplify your `find` command until it locates something near your data.

Comment: @jspcal Hey bro, can you please tell me how to do it ? i am a bit newbie, how to run raw $response

Comment: Try `print_r($response)` to see the raw response output.

Comment: @jspcal i try and it open the website in browser.

Comment: @jspcal please Help

Comment: Hmm try `echo(htmlspecialchars($response))` that will HTML-encode the output so you can view the source returned by the server in the browser.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214416/dont-parse-simple-html-dom-on-php-7-1

Comment: @jspcal this is the out i got https://i.imgur.com/QaFb7qC.png, can u please tell me how do i scrape the selected text