# scraping text in curl &simple_html_dom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape the price of product but it not working can someone please help, this is the code :

```
$curl->get('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32844492002.html');
$response = $curl->getRawResponse();
$html4 = new simple_html_dom();
$html4->load($response);
$price2 = $html4->find("div[class='product-price'] div[class='product-price-current'] span[class='product-price-value']",0)->plaintext;
echo $price2;
```

i get this error

> Notice: Trying to get property 'plaintext' of non-object

I want to scrape this price 
[image]

Comment: No error checking. Are you sure you're getting back from your method calls what you think should be getting back?

Comment: This is the same as your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814144/cant-scrape-price-in-html-dom-and-curl. Don't post new question to add information, edit the old one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't Scrape Price in HTML\_dom and curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814144/cant-scrape-price-in-html-dom-and-curl)