# Wordpress simple_html_dom.php admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

I've made as script using file_get_html. I'm now transfering it to a Wordpress site, and it doesn't seem to work.

Just trying to use it in a admin plugin.

Snippet below:

```
require('includes/simple_html_dom.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit_updateColors'])) {
        $qGetBrands = $mysqli->query("SELECT ... ");
        while ($rowBrands = $qGetBrands->fetch_assoc()) {

            $brandId = $rowBrands['cl_brand_Id'];
            $url =  "https://www.url.com". $rowBrands['cl_brand_url'];
            $html = file_get_html($url);
            $html->find('div[class=col-md-1p5]');

            foreach($html->find('div[class=col-md-1p5]') as $brandColors) {
                foreach ($brandColors->find('h3') as $brandColor) {
                    $p_brandColor = $brandColor->innertext;
                }

                foreach ($brandColors->find('img') as $ColorImg) {
                    $p_ColorImg = $ColorImg->src;
                }                   
                    echo $p_brandColor ." <br />";
                    echo $imgName['basename'] ." <br /> <br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

After while have started:
`echo "I'm here!!!"` 
Results: "I'm here!!!"

After first foreach:
`echo "I'm here!!!"` 
Results: Nothing

After $html = file_get_html($url);:
`echo "Result: ".$html;`
Results: Nothing, not even showing "Result"

Error messages:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on
>   boolean in
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Farbkarte/index.php:67 Stack
>   trace: #0 /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):
>   main_init('') #1
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
>   /home/xxx/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(224):
>   do_action('toplevel_page_f...') #4 {main} thrown
>   in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Farbkarte/index.php on
>   line 67

I have no idea how to proceed, and would love to get some help!
Outside wordpress, it works perfectly.

I hope I havent removed too much informaton.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good start would be to enable error reporting with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Start from there.. I suspect that some includes are missing and you have to use the global $db object to access the db in WP.

Comment: Thank you, Eriks! Looks like I've made a mistake by getting the error messages out, because earlier they weren't working. Now it doesn't look like if find find() in the file_get_html. Updatd main post. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by looking at [file_get_contents(): stream does not support seeking ／ When was PHP behavior about this changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685814/file-get-contents-stream-does-not-support-seeking-when-was-php-behavior-abo/44131040)

> On line 75 of simple_html_dom.php:
>
> $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
> I removed the reference to $offset:
>
> $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context);
> No my page works fine. Not taking liability for anything else it breaks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Moving my earlier comment and some more hints here.

A good start would be to enable error reporting with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Start from there.. I suspect that some includes are missing and you have to use the global $db object to access the DB in WP.

Looking at your errors - apparently, `$html` variable is boolean and not a htmlDOM object. According to [this](http://hookr.io/functions/file_get_html/), `file_get_html()` returns false, if fetched content is empty or exceeds MAX_FILE_SIZE.

Check if the URL you are retrieving really exists, you have rights to access it, and MAX_FILE_SIZE is set correctly