# WordPress website Warning: exif_imagetype(): stream does not support seeking

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried looking for empty spaces in my file but in my header of one of the views it throws the following error:

> Warning: exif_imagetype(): stream does not support seeking in /home/customer/www/panamafasteners.com/public_html/wp-includes /functions.php online 3265.

The line with `exif_imagetype` is the one throwing the error:

```php
function wp_get_image_mime( $file ) {
    /*
     * Use exif_imagetype() to check the mimetype if available or fall back to
     * getimagesize() if exif isn't available. If either function throws an Exception
     * we assume the file could not be validated.
     */
    try {
        if ( is_callable( 'exif_imagetype' ) ) {
            // ---- the line below errors! ----
            $imagetype = exif_imagetype( $file );
            $mime = ( $imagetype ) ? image_type_to_mime_type( $imagetype ) : false;
        } elseif ( function_exists( 'getimagesize' ) ) {
            // Don't silence errors when in debug mode, unless running unit tests.
            if ( defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG
                && ! defined( 'WP_RUN_CORE_TESTS' )
            ) {
                // Not using wp_getimagesize() here to avoid an infinite loop.
                $imagesize = getimagesize( $file );
            } else {
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.PHP.NoSilencedErrors
                $imagesize = @getimagesize( $file );
            }

            $mime = ( isset( $imagesize['mime'] ) ) ? $imagesize['mime'] : false;
        } else {
            $mime = false;
        }
```

Comment: When does it happen? what `$file` is? If you can ignore this *warning* using @ that's reasonable considering the author of this function also used @ a few lines ahead.

Comment: Hey! Since this applies to Wordpress, I would advice you to try to disable as much plugins as you can first. Usually these kind of errors are caused by a plugin acting out and not specifically your code. If that doesn't help, please add the code in your header to this question. The actual error is unlikely to be in Wordpress itself.

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to use an HTTP URL, instead of a file system path. https://stackoverflow.com/q/40816714/1427878